# jQuery Mobile styling: delayed initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm new to this jQM stuff, as well as AJAX.

I have a site that keeps a static header and footer, and replaces #mainContent div with external .html/.php pages.

What I am finding is that when I click one of the nav-bar tabs (included in the header), and the  #mainContent is replaced with another page, the jQuery Mobile-styling (of buttons, drop-down menus, etc) does not load right away.

Initially the default-style of buttons appears, then (if AJAX loads) a second later the page does a 'refresh-type blink', and the buttons are replaced with the jQM styled-versions.

Occasionally I get stuck with the AJAX 'loading circle', and the buttons retain their original style until the 'nav-bar link' is pressed again.

I know there's a perfectly good reason for this.

Research indicated that using "$(document).ready(function() { .... });" is not ideal for jQM. I replaced this in my navigation-script with "$(document).bind('pageinit', function() { .... });", which didn't really make a difference (though the navbuttons still work).

Here is my basic script initialization for my index.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
     <title>NoteVote</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./NV_home.css">
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div data-role="page" id="noteVote"> 
     <!-- HEADER -->
     <div data-role="header" align="middle" class="header">
        <img src="images/banner_post_it.png" align="middle" alt="Banner Image" height="100" width="250"/>
        <!-- NAVBAR -->
        <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="c" id="navBar">
           <ul>
              <li><a class="ui-btn" id="coursesButton">Courses</a></li>
              <li><a class="ui-btn" id="searchButton">Search</a></li>
              <li><a class="ui-btn" id="submitButton">Submit</a></li>
              <li><a class="ui-btn" id="accountButton">Account</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /NAVBAR -->
     </div>
     <!-- /HEADER -->

     <!-- 
        This is the MAIN  This is where the contents will be replaced
     -->
     <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id="mainContent">
        <div class="main">
        <p/>
                 content here.\
        </div>
     </div>
     <!-- /MAIN -->

     <!-- FOOTER -->
     <div data-role="footer" class="footer" id="footer">
        <?php
           require_once('../account.php'); 

           if ($account == "_")
           {
              echo "Not logged in";
           } else {
              echo "Logged in as " . $account;
           }
        ?>
     </div>
     <!-- /FOOTER -->

  </div>
  <!-- /INDEX -->
  <script src="./scripts/navScript.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

My navScript.js:

```
  $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {

      $("#coursesButton").on("click", function(e) {
          //e.preventDefault();
          //alert('courses');
          $("#mainContent").load("./pages/courses.html");
      });

      $("#searchButton").on("click", function(e) {
          //e.preventDefault();
          //alert('search');
          $("#mainContent").load("./pages/search.html");
      });

     $("#submitButton").on("click", function(e) {
          //e.preventDefault();
          //alert('submit');
          $("#mainContent").load("./pages/submit.html");
      });


      $("#accountButton").on("click", function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        //alert('account');
        $("#mainContent").load("./pages/accountPage.php");
      });

  });
```

And then here is one of my external pages loaded. This is where the button-styling doesn't load properly... (search.html):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
     <title>NoteVote</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./NV_home.css">
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id="mainContent">
        <div class="wrap">   
           <div class="main">
                 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="fieldcontain">
                 <form method="POST" action="./search_result.php">

                    <legend><h3>Course:</h3></legend>

                    <select name="course" id="customSelect">
                       <option value="*">All</option>
                       <option value="COMM2216">COMM-2216</option>
                       <option value="COMP2121">COMP-2121</option>
                       <option value="COMP2510">COMP-2510</option>
                       <option value="COMP2526">COMP-2526</option>
                       <option value="COMP2714">COMP-2714</option>
                       <option value="COMP2721">COMP-2721</option>
                    </select>
                    </fieldset>

                    <p/>
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="fieldcontain">
                       <legend><h4>Type:</h4></legend>
                       <input type="radio" name="type" value="lec" id="lec"/>
                          <label for="lec">Lecture</label>
                       <input type="radio" name="type" value="lab" id="lab">
                          <label for="lab">Lab</label>
                       <input type="radio" name="type" value="*" id="both" checked="checked">
                          <label for="both">Both</label>
                    <p/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Go">
                    </fieldset>
                 </form>
              </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  <script src="./scripts/searchGo.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

If you could give me a pointer as to why it takes a second to 'refresh' before the jQuery-Mobile style over-rides that of the standard HTML5, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I have a feeling it is due to the scripts/styles being loaded twice (ie in the index.php  and the search.html ), but if I do not load them in each page, then the buttons do not get stylized...

Though not really affecting basic functionality, it does give the web-app the appearance of really lagging.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are not *initializing* the content you are loading via Ajax. When you load external data dynamically, you need to manually *initialize* any jQuery Mobile's "widget".

All you need is to call `.enhanceWithin()` on `$("#mainContent")` after data is successfully loaded. Hence, you need to use `.load()`'s *callback function* to *initialize* those elements.

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', "#noteVote", function () {
    $("#coursesButton").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#mainContent").load("URL", function () {
            $(this).enhanceWithin();
        });
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/K82Ex/show/)** <sup>(1)</sup> - **[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/K82Ex/)**

<sup>(1) Click "Courses" or "Search" buttons</sup>

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you.
I had the scripts included in some of the pages <header>s still, which caused a duplicate-effect on buttons etc. After removing additional script links this problem no longer occurred and there was no 'lag' when transitioning pages.
Thanks!

Comment: @OscuroAA you're welcome, I'm glad it worked for you. Make sure you attach listeners during `pagecreate` And specify a page id, as in the code above. Read more about page events here http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/